# Subtypes of an interface only compatible with a subtype of another interface

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles

I've been scratching my head for a long time on a problem and I still don't know what would be the best solution. Since the application domain is very technical, I'll illustrate my problem with a simple example.

Suppose I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void feed(AnimalFood food);
}

public interface AnimalFood {
    // some methods
}
```

And the two following classes implementing the interfaces:

```
public class DogFood implements AnimalFood {
    // some methods
}

public class CatFood implements AnimalFood {
    // some methods
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    public void feed(AnimalFood food){
        // can only eat dog food
    }
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
    public void feed(AnimalFood food){
        // can only eat cat food
    }
}
```

This means that everytime I feed a `Dog` or a `Cat` instance, I'll have to validate if the received instance of `DogFood` or `CatFood` and throw an exception if this is not the right kind of food.

This smells bad to me, and I am pretty sure to violate the Liskov substitution principle!

Is there a design pattern, or what would be an elegant way to manage this situation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450793/visitor-pattern-for-two-arguments/30453212#30453212

This type of OO question is too frequent. Thankfully Eric did a great job in his series article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are using Java. If so you can use generics to restrict the type of the parameter in `feed`

```
public interface Animal<T extends AnimalFood> {
      void feed(T food);
}



public class Dog implements Animal<DogFood> {
    public void feed(DogFood food){
        // can only eat dog food
    }
}

public class Cat implements Animal<CatFood> {
    public void feed(CatFood food){
        // can only eat cat food
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question appears to be language agnostic I will answer in C# but the ideas will be applicable to Java and similar.

We *could* declare `IAnimalFood` as a generic interface but that would give a *compile* time error, not the runtime exception you asked for, if you try to feed cat food to a dog:

```
    void Main()
    {
        new Cat().Feed(new UserQuery.CatFood());
        new Dog().Feed(new UserQuery.CatFood()); // won't compile
    }
    
    public interface IAnimalFood { }
    
    public class DogFood : IAnimalFood { }
    
    public class CatFood : IAnimalFood { }
    
    public interface IAnimal<TFood> where TFood : IAnimalFood
    {
        void Feed(TFood food);
    }
    
    public class Dog : IAnimal<DogFood> {
        public void Feed(DogFood food){
            // can only eat dog food
        }
    }
    
    public class Cat : IAnimal<CatFood> {
        public void Feed(CatFood food){
            // can only eat cat food
        }
    }
```

There doesn't seem to be any reasonable run-time alternative to checking the *type* of the food supplied except a *declarative pattern* I have used before with success: add to the food type a *property* which specifies what food it is:

```
void Main()
{
    new Dog().Feed(new UserQuery.CatFood());
}

public enum FoodType
{
   CatFood,
   DogFood,
   BirdFeed
}

public interface IAnimalFood {
   FoodType TypeOfFood { get; }
}

public class DogFood : IAnimalFood {
   public FoodType TypeOfFood { get { return FoodType.DogFood; } }
}

public class CatFood : IAnimalFood
{
   public FoodType TypeOfFood { get { return FoodType.CatFood; } }
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    void Feed(IAnimalFood food);
}

public class Dog : IAnimal {
    public void Feed(IAnimalFood food){
        // can only eat dog food
        if (food.TypeOfFood != FoodType.DogFood)
         throw new Exception("You must be joking pal! I don't eat that!");
    }
}
```

Result:

> Exception
>
> You must be joking pal! I don't eat that!

Alternatively, have `AnimalFood`s implement a flags enumeration (bitfield) which specifies the types of animals that may eat them.

Either way (a type of food property or an animals that can eat me property):

- You do not have to type-check
- There are no compile-time constraints
- The type of food or the animals that can eat it is nicely
  encapsulated into the AnimalFood class

This could be combined with the factory idea suggested elsewhere, too.

Answer (score 0):

To compliment the accepted answer with Generics, it might be useful having all Animal instances be able to create their own type of food with via the Factory method design pattern.

Here's the GoF pattern:

[image: Factory Method pattern (GoF)]

Here's how to apply it to your case:

[image: Factory Method pattern applied (GoF)]